# Angular google Maps vs. ngMap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm building a web app with angularjs that need to display google map with markers and directions. For what I saw so far, there are two main google-map extensions for angluarJS:

https://github.com/nlaplante/angular-google-maps

and

http://ngmap.github.io/

For the angular-google-map: The community is larger but the documentation is lack of many important features (directions for example).

For the ngMap: the community is smaller but the documentation is much more extensive.

Which one would you recommend to use? Are there any main differences? Which one could be more "official" (to get longer support, etc...)?

Answer (score 0):

There are no differences. It's the same. It is your choice - to use JavaScript or Angular.

Comment: Is it same with respect to clustering support ?